# how to sort descending order of ObservableCollection into WP7.?

Tags: sorting, observablecollection

I want to sort my ObservableCollection into the Descending Order I had tried with different scenario but I am not able to sort it my code is like this.

1>

```
            LeaderboardItems = new ObservableCollection<AEGAPI.clsAEGAPI.Leaderboard>(LeaderboardItems.OrderByDescending(a => a.Points));
```

2>

```
                        LeaderboardItems.OrderByDescending(p => p.Points);
```

I had tried lots of but I am not able to get my result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can't sort a ObservableCollection, because than you are changing the collection. If you only want to show the sorted list:

```
List<AEGAPI.clsAEGAPI.Leaderboard> list = LeaderboardItems.OrderByDescending(p => p.Points).ToList()
```

Or you can directly bind the source to a listbox

```
listbox.ItemsSource = LeaderboardItems.OrderByDescending(p => p.Points)
```

The list will not react to changes on the observable collection. You have to implement it your self.

In the past i found someone who has made a sortable observable collection, maybe you can go for that option (search for : sortableobservablecollection), but is was a bit complex.

Greets